# Vue Multiselect multiple conditional remove on select

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I'm using this pretty package [Vue-Multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/), in `multiple` mode.

```html
<multiselect v-model="values" :options="options" :multiple="true"
   label="name" track-by="name" @select="select" @input="input"
>
</multiselect>
```

When adding an option, I'd like to remove the selected options with a different `group`

```js
const options = [
  { name: "Option 1", group: 1 },
  { name: "Option 2", group: 1 },
  { name: "Option 3", group: 2 },
];
```

Here if I select "Option 3", the other options must be removed from the selection
If I select "Option 2", "Option 3" must be removed but not "Option 1", etc..

First I though about using the `select` event to modify the selected values before `input`

```js
export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data() {
    values: [],
    options: options
  },
  methods: {
    select(option) {
      this.values = this.values.filter(value => value.group != option.group);
    },
    input(options) {
      console.log(options);
    },
  }
}
```

But it seems to be overwritten afterwards.

**On select, how can I remove the selected options with a different group ?**

Comment: v-model="value"  or v-model="values"?

Comment: Typo fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a watcher on "values" array (passed in v-model), and use following logic in the watcher.

```
watch: {
  values: {
    handler() {
      const len = values.length;
      this.values.splice(len-1, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

This will not overwrite the value.